# Data defined with DS statement

Tags: assembly, 8051

I'm doing a simple program that reads UART buffer (S0BUF)  on an incoming transmission and then transmits it back via the UART when I press a button.
I'm using the Nordic Semiconductor nRF24LE1 chip.

I get it to work with C and I get it to work when I use one of the R0-R7 registers.
What I want to do is to use a relocatable byte instead of the normal R-registers.

Here is a snippet of code that works.

```
UART_ISR: ; (Store incoming transmission in R0)
        JNB    RI0,    UART_ISR_A
        MOV    R0,     S0BUF
        SETB   P00
        CLR    RI0
        JMP    UART_ISR_END
UART_ISR_A:
        SETB   P01
        CLR    TI0
UART_ISR_END:           
        RETI


Main:
        MOV    A,       P2
        XRL    A,       #0x0FE
        JZ     Main_Case_A
        XRL    A,       #(0x0FE XOR 0x0FD)
        JZ     Main_Case_B
        ...

Main_Case_A:
        MOV    S0BUF,   R0
        SJMP   Main
```

But if I do the following changes (marked with <--- THIS) it wont work. I know I am missing out some segments and stuff in this snippet, but I don't want to many lines.

```
?DT?Data    segment     data                 ; <--- THIS

rseg     ?DT?Data                            ; <--- THIS
         RX_Message:    ds    1              ; <--- THIS

UART_ISR: ; (Store incoming transmission in R0)
            JNB    RI0,    UART_ISR_A
            MOV    RX_Message,     S0BUF        ; <-- THIS
            SETB   P00
            CLR    RI0
            JMP    UART_ISR_END
UART_ISR_A:
            SETB   P01
            CLR    TI0
UART_ISR_END:           
            RETI


Main:
        MOV    A,       P2
        XRL    A,       #0x0FE
        JZ     Main_Case_A
        XRL    A,       #(0x0FE XOR 0x0FD)
        JZ     Main_Case_B
        ...

Main_Case_A:
        MOV    S0BUF,   RX_Message     ;      <--- AND THIS
        SJMP   Main
```

It assembles and everything without warnings or errors but the result is not the same.

What I want is to let the assembler/linker to decide where in memory to put my RX_Message byte.
If I look in the list file I can see that it assigned it to address 0x00 which is fine by me since I'm not using R0 anywhere.. But I assumed that if I used R0 somewhere it would set my RX_Message address to 0x01 (or something else).. but that didn't happen.

What am I missing out? Or am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: I don't know 8051, but a quick google for how it memory maps registers told me that [they're banked](http://what-when-how.com/8051-microcontroller/8051-register-banks-and-stack/).  Are you sure that your code is using register bank 0?  If not, `R0` doesn't map to address `0x00`.

Comment: It's banked and I'm pretty sure I'm using the default bank.

Comment: Well, what address does change value when you modify `R0`?  You could sanity-check that with a debugger, right?  Although, re-reading your question, I would have to guess that the default behaviour is not to overlap your data segment with register banks.  Can you use a debugger to see what address is actually used by instructions that access `RX_Message`?  i.e. figure out what happened after linking?

Comment: You are right, it actually puts the RX_Message at mem pos 0x08

Comment: Okay something is strange, or at least I can't explain it.. RX_Message is put at mem pos 0x08 all fine so far! But program doesn't work as expected. However if I skip using the RX_Message label and just test various direct address. Tested 0x00 (R0), 0x07 (R7), 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x40... 0x08 and 0x09 won't work. The result isn't the same for 0x08 and 0x09 but they doesn't behave as expected. I know the SP is suppose to act on those addresses but I'm not PUSHing or POPing anything (unless it is hidden in some instruction). Any ideas @PeterCordes ?

Comment: I don't know 8051 and only partly read your code, but I'm glad I got you started on some useful debugging anyway :)  That does sound weird that the linker doesn't avoid the default stack.  But I guess on a system with so little memory, you're supposed to keep track of what's happening to every byte?  I haven't ever developed for any microcontroller, so IDK what's typical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution..
The stack is of course involved since I'm using interrupts (didn't mention that because I didn't think that was important.. Adding some code to reposition the stack solved the issue. Although I hoped that the linker wouldn't have put my RX_Message label on the stacks default address..